# Sending Google API OAuth2 response to Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, codeigniter-2

I am new to CodeIgniter and PHP.
Redirect URL given in Google API Console:

```
Redirect URIs:  http://localhost/testsaav/index.php/main/gmail_invite
```

Following code shows me Request For Permission page. When I click `Allow Access` it takes me to

```
http://localhost/testsaav/index.php/main/gmail_invite?code=4/CXD462cen-oEBe1GaHIH90hjqb2X.QpVsg7mG4AUXaDn_6y0ZQNgaCVLxeAI
```

I want to redirect it to another page and show the response there. Controller method

```
function gmail_invites($data)
{
   $this->load->view('socialInvites2',$data);

}
```

View implementation

```
<?php 
            require_once APPPATH.'libraries/Google_Client.php';
            session_start();
            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName('Google Contacts PHP Sample');
            $client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
            $client->setClientId('xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
            $client->setClientSecret('xxx-xxx');
            $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/testsaav/index.php/main/gmail_invite');

            if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
              $client->authenticate();
              $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
              $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
              header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            }

            if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
             $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
            }

            if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
              unset($_SESSION['token']);
              $client->revokeToken();
            }

            if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
              $req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
              $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
              //$xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
              //$result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');

              /*foreach ($result as $title) {
                echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
              }*/
              // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
              $response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));
              //print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>";

              // The access token may have been updated lazily.
              $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
            } else {
              $auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
            }

            print "<a class='facebook-button' id='facebookbutton' href='$auth'>
            <span class='fb-button-left'></span>
            <span class='fb-button-center'>Invite GMail Friends</span>
            <span class='fb-button-right'></span></a>"; ?>
            <br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have all that php code in your view? That's not how MVC works.

Logic code should be kept in your Controller and not your View. I suggest that you use a Codeiginter OAuth2 library because the original code from Google's OAuth2 lib isn't meant to be compatible with Codeiginter or any other particular MVC framework. For example you could use this one: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2

You're being redirected to the correct controller because the url is set here:

```
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/testsaav/index.php/main/gmail_invite');
```

Also take a look at Codeigniter's redirect method:
 `redirect('somecontroller/some_method')`