# Codeigniter: Redirect to another URL from view page

Tags: php, codeigniter

google-php-client example calls the authorization URL when user clicks a link. I want to call it when page loads without any user click.
The way it is implemented in google-client example:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Contacts PHP Sample');
$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
$auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
print "<a class=login href='$auth'>Connect Me!</a>";
```

I am trying to remove dependency on clicking on `Connect Me` link and call url given by `$client->createAuthUrl()`. I am new to Codeigniter that's why struggling on this simple task.
I check that there are following different ways to call an URL but not sure which one will work here:

1. cURL
2. file_get_contents
3. stream_context_create

I am using php 5.3 with XAMPP

Comment: From your example, the authorization appears to be occurring for the connecting client (presumably, a browser). Are you looking to authenticate via PHP so that the PHP application is authorized, not the client? Or are you just wanting to redirect the client itself?

Comment: This is a duplicate post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541567/sending-google-api-oauth2-response-to-controller/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple redirect using CodeIgniter's libraries, use the following:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Contacts PHP Sample');
$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
$auth = $client->createAuthUrl();

$this->load->helper('url');
redirect($auth); // Returns a HTTP redirect to the client
```

This is a wrapper around `header('Location: ... ');` when no second parameter is passed (or is passed as `'location'`).

Answer (score 1):

Just use redirect from [url helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) or alternative  :

```
echo '<script>window.location = "'.$your_location.'"</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the php function!

```
header('Location: $auth', TRUE, 301);
```

Since we're talking about Codeigniter, it would be ***more appropriate*** to use the built-in **redirect()**

```
 //loading the helper
 $this->load->helper('url');
 redirect($auth);
```

more reading on the Codeigniter [URL Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: CI has a built-in redirect which would make more sense if you want to maintain consistent use of the framework.